# undefined variable variable declaration in PHP and array to string convertion

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

For some reason I am getting undefined variable and string to array conversion
I don't understand why either of these is happening

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: body in C:\Users\New\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\yakov\sendemail.php</b> on line <b>20

Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\Users\New\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\yakov\sendemail.php on line 33
"Array'services.html:  ''services.html'\n\n'new york:  ''new york'\n\n'new york:  ''new york'\n\n'round_trip:  ''round_trip'\n\n'2016-09-16:  ''2016-09-16'\n\n'2016-09-23:  ''2016-09-23'\n\n'nonstop:  ''nonstop'\n\n'flexible:  ''flexible'\n\n'Business:  ''Business'\n\n'1 Adult:  ''1 Adult'\n\n'some:  ''some'\n\n'one:  ''one'\n\n'someonesemail@gmail.com:  ''someonesemail@gmail.com'\n\n'new york:  ''new york'\n\n'dsfa\n:  ''dsfa\n'\n\n'4127117117:  ''4127117117'\n\n'me:  ''me'\n\n;"
```

here is my code that is causing the problem I tried playing around with it

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us. We will contact you as early as possible.'
    );
    //print phpinfo(); 
    error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//set_error_handler("var_dump");
$body;
$email;
$subject;
$email_from;
$email_to = 'Sales@ElyonTravel.com';
if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
    $body;
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST[$key])) {
            $body .= "'". $_REQUEST[$key] .":  '" . $val . "\n\n";
        }

    }
$email = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['email'])) : "NA";
$subject = isset($_REQUEST['subject']) ? trim(stripslashes($_REQUEST['subject'])) : "NA";
    $body .= ";";
    $email_from = $email;
    //$email_to = 'Sales@Travel.com';// your email
    $body;
}
$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status .$body);
//}
    die;
```

any other suggestions would be appreciated since I am new to the back end

Comment: first of all: you are doing just $body; a lot. Start by defining it as a string and don't redefine it ($body = '';)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with this:

```
$body;
```

I see three stray `$body;`'s in your code. Get those out of there. As mentioned in the comments, just define it once as a string at the top:

```
$body = "";
```

Then you can concatenate other strings to it all you wish.

The array to string error is probably due to the fact that you're trying to concatenate a string with an array:

```
echo json_encode($status .$body); 
// ^-- this won't work. $status is an array. $body is a string.
```

If you're just echoing out that json for fun, you could always add your body string to that status array and then echo it out:

```
$status['body'] = $body;
echo json_encode($status);
```